# How can I simplify this function which tests for a sequence

Tags: java, arrays

```
 public boolean Stairs() {
    Arrays.sort(collector);
    for (int c = 0; c < collector.length; c++) {
        if (collector[5] - collector[4]==1 && collector[4] - collector[3]==1 && collector[3] - collector[2]==1 && collector[2] - collector[1]==1 && collector[1] - collector[0]==1) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

This function should test if there is sequence at play.

My idea was: `if(collector[c]==collector[c+1]+1)`, but I get an out of bounds exception each time I run it, so basically I am looking for help to find a way to refactor this function into a more efficient one.

Comment: Change your condition to `c < collector.length - 1` then your second version should work.

Comment: you need to provide more details, like what `collector` how it looks like, what sequence are you searching, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think @Chris Parker has an important point.  You're answer is currently not testing if the *entire* array is sequenced, just if the *first 2 elements* are.  What you need to do is:

```
public boolean Stairs() {
    Arrays.sort(collector);
    for (int c = 0; c < collector.length -1; c++) {
        if (collector[c] != collector[c+1] - 1) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

That way you only return `true` once you've verified all the numbers follow the fixed increment; if you find any transition that doesn't fit, you can immediately return `false`.

Comment: I suspect you just get the OP an answer to homework. :)

Comment: Works perfectly! , correct me if i am wrong so basically i test if any of the positions in the array "don't" meet my conditions placed by the if. So the program only reaches true if this is the case. Which is correct since what i did was basically testing the same but as soon as one position meets my demands i return True which causes to stop the loop , only returning false if genuinely no Position at all met my demands.

Comment: @ChrisParker I know...  But with *2* wrong answers to the question I couldn't resist the compulsion to **say** something. :)

Answer (score 0):

Your current version doesn't need a for loop since `i` is never used. You are also assuming that there are exactly 6 elements in the sequence.

Your second version is much more correct. You just need to be careful with your counter because of `collector[c+1]`. This means you need to stop the loop one element sooner than you currently are. Just change the for loop condition to `c < collector.length - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

You can campare the array from position 0 to position collector.length -1. But, before it, you should check if the length is greater than 1.

```
for (int c = 0; c < collector.length-1; c++){
    if(collector[c] - collector[c+1] == 1)
        return true
}
return false;
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!, i tested your recommendations and this works:

```
 public boolean Stairs() {
    Arrays.sort(collector);
    for (int c = 0; c < collector.length -1; c++){
        if(collector[c] == collector[c+1]-1)
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Test this: [0, 1, 3, 987, 56834, 15]...  Do you get the results you expect? Because your code is inconsistent with "&&" in the very first version.

Comment: Yeah i know the second version seems to be working more consistently, the first was just an act of desperation and bad coding.

Comment: You miss my point I think:  The version of code we are commenting on will return true on the *FIRST* loop, and not bother to check the remaining values.  It doesn't explode, but it doesn't bother to check the remaining values.  Don't *think* about the array I presented, actually *test* it and see if you get the results you expect.

Comment: Tested it and you are right, it only tests the first loop and if True it doesn't check the remaining positions.